# Maximize the minimum distance between the same elements

Tags: python, algorithm, sequence, combinatorics

I have an array, for example:

```
arr = ['A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B']
```

I want to reorder this array such that the minimum distance between elements of same type is the maximum. For example, this is the best sequence for the above array:

```
arr1 = ['A', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'A']
```

How can I do that in python? I'm having a hard time figuring it out...

Edit: I tried to solve it with genetic algorithm such that each individual is a sequence of integers, for example, [1 ,2, 3, 6, 4, 5] and this means that positions 1 and 2 will be swapped, 3 and 6, 4 and 5. However it seems to stuck on local minima.

Comment: What if the list is like this - ```['A', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'A']```    Does the list only have 2 items or more?

Comment: The list must keep the number of elements for each category, so in my example, it would be 3 A's and 2 B's.

Comment: Start with a naive approach: figure out how to determine whether a given list satisfies your criteria, and then test all permutations of a list to see which one does.  Once you get that working you can start thinking about how to optimize it.  Have you made any progress on the first part or are you completely stuck on how to test the "distances" between identical elements?

Comment: If the array is `['A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B']`, what is the best sequence for the array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here a "bruteforce attack on the output" solution. It doesn't provide a perfect result, it works better on bigger lists, it's generally faster than other solutions found online. Useful if you need speed instead of precision.

```
from collections import defaultdict

def find_nearest_none(arr, position):
    if arr[position] is None:
        return position

    step = 1
    while True:
        left_pos = position - step
        right_pos = position + step

        if right_pos < len(arr) and arr[right_pos] is None:
            return right_pos
        elif left_pos >= 0 and arr[left_pos] is None:
            return left_pos
        elif left_pos < 0 and right_pos >= len(arr):
            # Both left and right positions are out of bounds
            return False

        step += 1

def max_distance_list(nums):
    num_occurrences = {}
    t = len(nums)

    # Works on a lit that doesn't contains None
    out = [None] * t
    
    # Group data by occurence count
    for num in nums:
        num_occurrences[num] = num_occurrences.get(num, 0) + 1
    num_occurrences = sorted(num_occurrences.items(), key=lambda item: item[1], reverse=True)

    # Create a dict from touple list
    # grouped_data_dict new format => {10: [3], 4: [1, 5], 2: [44, 4, 6], 1: [7, 8, 9, 11, 123, 22]})
    grouped_data = defaultdict(list)
    for key, value in num_occurrences:
        grouped_data[value].append(key)  
    
    start_pos = 0   # start position
    it = 0          # iterations

    # iterate over the grouped data, beginning from the items that occurr most
    for x, y in dict(grouped_data).items():

        # iterate over list of items with same occurrences
        for z in y:
        
            # calculate the optimal separation between them
            sep = (t+1) / x # keep it as a float and round it up later
            pos = start_pos; # 0,1,2 increase for each uniq element in array
            it += 1;  
            # Iterate over every occurrence of every element
            for i in range(x): 
                
                # Write the last occurrence nearest the end as possible
                if i == x-1:
                    pos = t-it;

                # get the nearest free position to the oprimal one
                free_pos = find_nearest_none(out, int(round(pos,0)))

                # write the element in the out array
                out[free_pos] = z

                # Increment position by optimal (float) separation
                pos+=sep;

            start_pos+=1;
    return out
```

You can see the imperfections rate in the image, but also the speed

[image: Test on 2k random numbers]

Some tests

```
    [my_func] elements: 2000  -- Tot time: 0.0010275840759277344
    [1, 1, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 44, 4, 5, 6, 1, 4, 5, 3, 6, 7, 8, 9, 11, 123, 22, 44, 1, 5, 5] 
    --> 
    [3, 1, 5, 3, 44, 4, 3, 6, 22, 3, 1, 5, 3, 123, 11, 9, 3, 1, 5, 3, 8, 7, 3, 6, 4, 3, 44, 5, 1, 3]
    AABCBAD --> ['A', 'B', 'D', 'A', 'C', 'B', 'A']
    AAA --> ['A', 'A', 'A']
    AAB --> ['A', 'B', 'A']
    AABBC --> ['A', 'B', 'C', 'B', 'A']
    AABBBCC --> ['B', 'A', 'C', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'B']
```

Answer (score 1):

This seems to work and is similiar. I'll leave this here for reference. I had an interview question that required this. Here is my solution. This takes a second parameter k which is the minimum desired distance between duplicate values. The algorithm does its best to seperate duplicates by k indexes. I believe you can get the maximum spacing by making k = lengthOfArray/maxOcurrenceOfValue.

```
def maxTime(deliveries, x):
    ans = []
    count = {}
    for n in deliveries:
        count[n] = count.setdefault(n, 0)+1
    keys = sorted([k for k in count.keys()], key=lambda x: count[x], reverse=True)
    while len(count) >0:
        ind = 0
        l = 0
        while l < x and ind < len(keys):
            ans.append(keys[ind])
            l+=1
            count[keys[ind]] -=1
            
            if count[keys[ind]] == 0:
                count.pop(keys[ind])
                keys.pop(ind)
            else:
                ind+=1
    print(ans)

maxTime(["A","A","A","A","B", "B","C", "C", "D", "E"], 3) # math.ceil(len/maxOccur) = 3
# -> ['A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'D', 'E', 'A']
maxTime(["A","A","A","A","B", "B","C", "C", "D", "E"], 5) # alternative k
# -> ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'A']
maxTime(["A","A","B","A","B","B","C","C","E","D"],4) # math.ceil(len/maxOccur) = 4 
# -> ['A', 'B', 'C', 'E', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'A', 'B']
```

Answer (score -1):

I don't know if anyone is still interested in having an answer to this question, but since my first naive attempt was incorrect and properly downgraded, it got my design juices going.  So here is a more complete answer.

As I understand the problem:
Given a sequence of symbols such as "AAABB"
where A & B are the symbols
Find a reordering of the sequence such that the minimum separation between like symbols is maximized.
So in the above example, the solution would be "ABABA"

```
import heapq as hpq
from copy import copy
from dataclasses import dataclass
from itertools import permutations
from functools import total_ordering


@dataclass
@total_ordering
class SolutionItem:
    arr: str
    sol: list[str]

    def __lt__(self, other):
        return len(self.arr) < len(other.arr)


def min_separation(in_arr, all_symbs):
    # compute the mininimum separation between symbols
    for s in all_symbs:
        locs = [i for i, x in enumerate(in_arr) if x == s]
        if len(locs) > 1:
            return min([locs[x] - locs[x-1] - 1 for x in range(1, len(locs))])
        return 0


def maximize_min_separation(arr):
    """ find the organization of symbols in arr to produce the maximum
        possible minimum separation between equal symbols
    """
    all_symbs = set(arr)
    h = []
    best = min_separation(arr, all_symbs)
    best_sol = arr
    hpq.heappush(h, (best, SolutionItem(arr, [])))
    while len(h) > 0:
        mindist, itm = hpq.heappop(h)
        cur_arr = itm.arr
        cur_sol = itm.sol
        if len(cur_arr) > 0:
            options = set(cur_arr)
            nxt_arr = copy(cur_arr)
            for s in options:
                k = nxt_arr.find(s)
                nxt_arr = nxt_arr[:k] + nxt_arr[k+1:]

            for opt in permutations(options):
                if cur_sol:
                    nxt_sol_frt = list(opt)
                    nxt_sol_frt.extend(cur_sol)
                    nxt_sol_bck = copy(cur_sol)
                    nxt_sol_bck.extend(list(opt))
                    frt_itm = SolutionItem(nxt_arr, nxt_sol_frt)
                    bck_itm = SolutionItem(nxt_arr, nxt_sol_bck)
                    hpq.heappush(h, (-min_separation(frt_itm.sol, all_symbs),
                                     frt_itm))
                    hpq.heappush(h, (-min_separation(bck_itm.sol, all_symbs),
                                     bck_itm))
                else:
                    frt_itm = SolutionItem(nxt_arr, list(opt))
                    hpq.heappush(h, (-min_separation(list(opt),
                                                     all_symbs), frt_itm))
        else:
            # come here for a solution
            if mindist < best:
                best_sol = cur_sol
    return ''.join(best_sol)
```

Executing `maximize_min_separation` for several test cases produces the following results:

```
Case: AAA --> AAA
Case: AAB --> ABA
Case: AABBB --> BABAB
Case: AABBC --> CBABA
Case: AABBBCC --> BCABACB
Case: AABCBAD --> BACABDA
```

Which seem to satisfy the requirements.

Comment: BACABDA isn't optimal, ABCABDA is better.

Comment: ABCABDA isn't perfect, ABCADBA and ABDACBA are better

Answer (score -2):

If I understand what you are trying to do.
Given an List of elements such as ['A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B']

Provide a new List such that:

1. all elements of the input list are used
2. there is a maximum distance between each repeated element

producing for example the output from above input of ['A', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'A']

The following code implements this functionality

```
from collections import Counter
def processList(arr: list) -> list:
    cd = []
    for k,v in Counter(arr).items():
        cd.append([k,v])
    cd = sorted(cd, key= lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)
    rslt = []
    while sum([x[1] for x in cd]) > 0:
        seq = []
        for i in range(len(cd)):
            if cd[i][1] > 0:
                seq.append(cd[i][0])
                cd[i][1] -= 1
        rslt.extend(seq)
    return rslt
```

Thus using your example as a test:

```
processList(['A', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'A'])
```

yields:

```
['A', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'A']
```

Comment: `processList('AAABC')` fails.

Comment: Please note 'AAABC' is not a list, which is contrary to the base assumptions of the solution provided

Comment: ```processList('AAABC')``` generates an output = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'A'].   There is no clear definition of what is and isn't acceptable, so explain why you conclude this fails.

Comment: String, list, not important to show the issue. The title says *"Maximize the minimum distance between the same elements"*. The body says *"minimum distance between elements of same type is the maximum"*. You're not doing that, as my example shows. You put two `A` next to each other, but it's possible to order that input so that no two same values are next to each other, which has a larger minimum distance.

Comment: Fair enough, good point