# Sort lists keeping maximum distance between repeating elements

Tags: python, list, logic

Given a list, ie:
[1,1,2,2,3,5]

I'd like to reorder it:
[1,2,3,5,1,2]

---

**EDIT after the comment: Final goal is to maximizes the smallest distance between any two occurrences of the same number, or minimize the closeness of repeating elements and spread them out as much as possible in the list**

Duplicate questions:
[Algorithm to separate items of the same type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12375831/algorithm-to-separate-items-of-the-same-type/76792233#76792233)

[Maximize the minimum distance between the same elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75701937/maximize-the-minimum-distance-between-the-same-elements/76792326#76792326)

I came up with this solution, that's the onw I'll use, if nothing better will be proposed:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/76792326/5053475

---

What alghoritm can I use?

Proceeding by logic:
I was thinking on calculate the occurencies, let's say, ie:
[1, 1, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 44, 4, 5, 6, 1, 4, 5, 3, 6, 7, 8, 9, 11, 123, 22, 44, 1, 5, 5]

would give this "occurency count" matrix 2x30:
[(3, 10), (1, 4), (5, 4), (44, 2), (4, 2), (6, 2), (7, 1), (8, 1), (9, 1), (11, 1), (123, 1), (22, 1)]

so I would:

- calculate all the numbers that have more than 1 repetition, in this case, 6 numbers
- There are 3 numbers with 2 occurrences:

  - The 6, it will go in poisition 3 (0+5-2) and 24 (29-5)
  - The 4, will go in positions 4 (0+5-1) and 25 (29-5+1)
  - The 44, will go in positions 5 (0+5) and 26 (29-5+2)
- There are 2 numbers with 4 occurencies

  - The 5 will go between positions 1 (0+6-3-1) and 27 (29-6+3), every aprox 6 numbers
  - The 1 will go between positions 2 (0+6-3) and 28 (29-6+3+1), every aprox 6 numbers
- There is 1 number with 10 occurencies

  - The 3 will go between positions 0 and 29, every aprox 3 numbers.

And so on.
Then fullfill the empty position with the non repeating numbers.
When some collision (position already occupied) alternate +1, -1, +2, -2 and so on till find a free position
I came up with this code, that boldly follow my algorithm,

```
from collections import defaultdict

def find_nearest_none(arr, position):
    if arr[position] is None:
        return position

    step = 1
    while True:
        left_pos = position - step
        right_pos = position + step

        if left_pos >= 0 and arr[left_pos] is None:
            return left_pos
        elif right_pos < len(arr) and arr[right_pos] is None:
            return right_pos
        elif left_pos < 0 and right_pos >= len(arr):
            # Both left and right positions are out of bounds
            return False

        step += 1

def max_distance_list(nums):
    num_occurrences = {}
    t = len(nums)
    out = [None] * t
    
    for num in nums:
        num_occurrences[num] = num_occurrences.get(num, 0) + 1
    num_occurrences = sorted(num_occurrences.items(), key=lambda item: item[1], reverse=True)

    grouped_data = defaultdict(list)
    for key, value in num_occurrences:
        grouped_data[value].append(key)

    print(grouped_data)

    start_pos = 0 
    for x, y in dict(grouped_data).items():
        print("Start pos:", start_pos)
        for z in y:
            sep = t // x
            pos = start_pos;
            for i in range(x):
                free_pos = find_nearest_none(out, pos)
                out[free_pos] = z 
                pos+=sep;
            start_pos+=1;
    return out
```

Output: [3, 1, 5, 3, 44, 4, 3, 6, 1, 3, 5, 7, 3, 8, 1, 3, 5, 44, 3, 4, 6, 3, 1, 5, 3, 9, 11, 3, 123, 22]

but that's not an optimal result, it's just acceptable, and far away to be fast.
Is there some "already done" function to do this, better and faster?

If not, I'll proceed in chunks and will use this 'acceptable' result since
it's for creating a queue a crawler, to distantiate calls to the same IP and/or domains

Appreciate any help

Comment: Your criteria "maximum distance between repeating elements" is unclear.   Please describe precisely what you want maximized, so that we could unambiguously calculate the maximized value given a list of integers.  (For example, you might be trying to maximize the minimum distance between any repeating elements, or the sum of minima per each repeating element, or the sum of all repeat lengths, etc, etc....)

Comment: Thanks for the comment, my idea was to arrange the elements in the list in a way that maximizes the smallest distance between any two occurrences of the same number. So, I want to minimize the closeness of repeating elements and spread them out as much as possible in the list. The final goal is to achieve the greatest possible separation between the occurrences of any repeating element.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75701937/maximize-the-minimum-distance-between-the-same-elements is a duplicate.  There isn't a correct answer, however.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12375831/algorithm-to-separate-items-of-the-same-type also seems like a duplicate.

Comment: I love the tobias_k solution (https://stackoverflow.com/a/12376710/5053475), thanks to point it out. It's far away perfect in the output. The only problem is time: 42 seconds for 2k elements, while my not-optimized script took 0.0099 seconds. As far as I understand that's a quite complex problem in computational way. I need to decide if to keep speed, or quality.

Comment: About duplicate question, you are right. I'm not so expert here, what do you suggest? Delete this, and write my solution as an answer there? Or could I try to keep it some time to check if somebody comes out with a solution that it's either "better then mine" and "fast" at the same time?

Comment: So, do the numbers even have to be sorted, or are the distances the only success criteria?  Because I don't know how you guarantee "sorting" under that constraint.

Comment: No other sorting is necessary, I need it for a crawler, to keep calls to the same IP as much separate as possible; I came out with a working solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/76792326/5053475 but I don't know if it can be improved

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the Counter class to determine how many of each number you have.  then progressively build the list in ascending order of counts.  The unique numbers will go first., Then for numbers that are there twice, the farthest spread would be one at the beginning and one at the end.  Beyond two repetitions, you still want one at the beginning and one at the end but the remaining ones should spread evenly by splitting the list in count-1 chunks.

For example, Y repeated 4 times should place one at the start, one at the end and the other two splitting the items in 3 chunks.

```
...... --> Y..Y..Y..Y
```

Here's what the function could look like:

```
from collections import Counter

def spread(A):
    result   = []
    for value,count in reversed(Counter(A).most_common()):
        result.append(value)
        if count == 1: continue
        result.insert(0,value)
        if count == 2: continue
        chunk,extra = divmod(len(result)-2,count-1)
        i = 0
        for _ in range(count-2):
            i += chunk + 1 + (extra>0)
            extra -= 1
            result.insert(i,value)           
    return result
```

output:

```
A = [1,1,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,44,4,5,6,1,4,5,3,6,7,8,9,11,123,22,44,1,5,5]
spread(A)
[3,1,5,44,3,4,6,22,3,5,1,3,123,11,3,9,8,3,5,1,3,7,6,3,4,44,3,5,1,3]
```

For comparison purposes, here is a function that computes the distances between repeated items returning how many instances are at each distance.

```
def repDist(A):
    c = Counter(A[i:].index(n)+1 for i,n in enumerate(A,1) if n in A[i:])
    return dict(sorted(c.items()))

OP = [3,1,5,3,44,4,3,6,1,3,5,7,3,8,1,3,5,44,3,4,6,3,1,5,3,9,11,3,123,22]

                   # {distance:count}
repDist(OP)        # {3: 9, 6: 2, 7: 2, 8: 2, 13: 2, 14: 1}
repDist(spread(A)) # {3: 7, 4: 2, 7: 1, 9: 5, 16: 1, 19: 1, 22: 1}
```

Comparison matching instance counts:

```
        |----9---| |--------6--------| |------------3--------------|
OP:     {3:9,      6:2, 7:2, 8:2,      13:2, 14:1}
spread: {3:7, 4:2,      7:1,      9:5,             16:1, 19:1, 22:1}
```

**[EDIT] Improved version**:

Inspired by Swifty's comments, I made an improved version that processes values with the same number of repetitions as a group.  This covers more edge cases and gives a more regular distribution of these same-repetition groups. It gives them equal spread distances instead of favouring the later values over earlier values with the same repetition count:

```
def spread2(A):
    countGroups = dict()
    for value,count in Counter(A).items():
        countGroups.setdefault(count,[]).append(value)
    result   = []
    for count,values in sorted(countGroups.items()):
        result.extend(values)
        if count == 1: continue
        result[:0] = values
        if count == 2: continue
        chunk,extra = divmod(len(result)-2*len(values),count-1)
        i = 0
        for _ in range(count-2):
            i += chunk + len(values) + (extra>0)
            extra -= 1
            result[i:i] = values
    return result
```

output:

```
spread2([1,1,2,2,3,5])  # [1, 2, 3, 5, 1, 2]
spread2([1,1,2,2,3,3])  # [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3]

spread2(A)
[3,1,5,44,3,4,6,7,3,1,5,3,8,9,3,11,123,3,1,5,3,22,44,3,4,6,3,1,5,3]

repDist(spread2(A))     #  {3: 7, 4: 2, 8: 2, 9: 4, 19: 3}
```

Comparison:

```
         |----9---| |--------6--------| |------------3--------------|
OP:      {3:9,      6:2, 7:2, 8:2,      13:2, 14:1}
spread:  {3:7, 4:2,      7:1,      9:5,             16:1, 19:1, 22:1}
spread2: {3:7, 4:2,           8:2, 9:4,                   19:3}
```

*BTW if speed is a concern, `spread2` processes a 2000 item list in 0.00025 to 0.00050 sec. depending on repetition patterns*

Comment: Nice approach, but there are still edge cases where it would partially fail (A = [1,1,2,2,3,3] for example). Not that my code is better, mind you; this problem is actually more difficult than I anticipated.

Comment: Thinking about this edge case some more, I think the problem comes from the values with count = 2; perhaps it would be better to first add the single values (S) like you do, then for the 'double' values (A, B, C, D...) place them this way: ABCD... S...S ABCD... (instead of ABCD... S...S ...DCBA), then do as you already did for the values with count >= 3; that would ensure* no consecutive identical values. * Provided there are no sneakier edge cases :)

Comment: Interesting. There would probably be a need to process items with equal counts as a single group of sequences.  Then [1,1,2,2,3,3] would be treated as (1,2,3) x 2 and the logic to place them first and last would produce [1,2,3,1,2,3].  I may add that to my answer when/if I get more time to play with it.

Comment: Interesting idea indeed, which would prevent overcomplexifying the code.

Comment: Interesting. That's a really good approach. A perefect solution form my use case.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple algorithm.

What I do here is look at each element in the list.  If I have not seen it this pass, I add it to my "gather" set.  If I HAVE seen it, I put it on a new list to check during the next pass.  After I've passed through the list, I sort the gathered elements and add them to the output.  Rinse and repeat until there's nothing left to process.

```
def reorder(undone):
    out = []
    while undone:
        gather = set()
        nextu = []
        for n in undone:
            if n in gather:
                nextu.append(n)
            else:
                gather.add(n)
        out.extend( sorted(gather) )
        undone = nextu
    return out

t1 = [1,1,2,2,3,5]
t2 = [1, 1, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 44, 4, 5, 6, 1, 4, 5, 3, 6, 7, 8, 9, 11, 123, 22, 44, 1, 5, 5]

print(reorder(t1))
print(reorder(t2))
```

Output:

```
[1, 2, 3, 5, 1, 2]
[1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 11, 22, 44, 123, 1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 44, 1, 3, 5, 1, 3, 5, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3]
```

Comment: Thanks I tried this approach too, but the tail of 3s doesn't get what I was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

I can't think of a better algorithm than the one you implemented, but I coded a shorter (and hopefully faster) implementation of it; the nested loops can certainly be improved, but I don't have a clear idea of how for now; I also work in reverse (to be able to delete from `free_indexes` while looping on it):

```
from collections import Counter

in_list = [1, 1, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 44, 4, 5, 6, 1, 4, 5, 3, 6, 7, 8, 9, 11, 123, 22, 44, 1, 5, 5]

out_list = [None] * len(in_list)
free_indexes = list(range(len(in_list)))
occurences = sorted(Counter(in_list).items(), key=lambda it:-it[1])

for value, count in occurences:
    first = len(free_indexes) - 1
    (step, last) = divmod(first, count - 1) if count > 1 else (1, first)
    for i in range(first, last - 1, -step):
        out_list[free_indexes[i]] = value
        free_indexes.remove(free_indexes[i])

print(out_list)

# [5, 1, 3, 44, 4, 3, 6, 22, 3, 5, 1, 3, 123, 11, 3, 9, 8, 3, 5, 1, 3, 7, 6, 3, 4, 44, 3, 5, 1, 3]
```

Comment: Hmmm, after some more tests, it seems beginning with the most represented values (as I did) is a bad idea; I'll fix my implementation to follow your algorithm more closely!